# Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: boot, kernel, init

[image]

This is what I've got. I cannot boot and I see the two of three little lights on the keyboard blinking all the time and the cooling is working on full power, almost.

I saw in other askubuntu topic suggestion for memory test. I did it. I didn't have any errors.

I am 99,9% sure it is not a hardware problem, because I have Windows 7 and I can boot it and it works just fine.

This problem came without any warning or something. I just turned off the laptop one day and at the other day I couldn't boot.

From recovery mode I get this:

[image]

Comment: At the GRUB screen select the entry you wish to boot in to (most likely the one that's selected as default), press `e` and then remove 'quiet' and 'splash' from the kernel line if present. You can then press Ctrl-X to boot. This might display a little more information that could be useful. Edit: tumbleweed's suggestion is better, try rescue mode

Comment: It doesn't boot in rescue mode. It is stuck at the same error. I'm wondering how to copy/paste all the information from the rescue screen.

Comment: Could you grab `/var/log/kern.log` from your Ubuntu partition using a Live CD?

Comment: I've same issue while I dist upgrade from 14.04, I'm even not able to boot with old kernel and rescue more, how did you solve it. ????

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There you go `/sbin/init: No such file or directory`. Looks like it can't find a `/sbin/init` on `/dev/sda6`.

Maybe have a look from a Live CD, and see what is on `sda6`? Is it the right partition? Is just that file missing?

You can probably fix it from a Live CD, but I'm not sure what caused it, so I can't give instructions. Reinstalling is probably easier, if you don't know how to fix it, yourself.

Comment: On sda6 I have the Ubuntu OS. It is the right partition. I've booted from a LiveCD and I see the /sbin/init file in /dev/sda6.

I actually don't know how to fix the /sbin/init, but I don't want to reinstall the OS for sure. Help me out fixing the init.

PS: Before I post the topic here I did partition check with Gparted from Live CD. It didn't helped.

Comment: It seems I will reinstall the OS after all.

Comment: I hate to have to suggest that, I'm sure it's fixable, but hard to say how, without sitting down and playnig with the machine...

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 . But i cannot even reinstall from the USB bootable ubuntu 14.04. There is a black screen with grub command prompt

Comment: I've same issue while I dist upgrade from 14.04, I'm even not able to boot with old kernel and rescue more, how did you solve it. ????

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, I think that this problem is caused by upgrading to a newer kernel version.

Force shutdown and then power on again. Select the *Advance* option for Ubuntu or Elementary. In the next tab, just choose a previous kernel version and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will go to desktop normally.

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of trouble with that same **exact problem** and it took me a while but i managed to fix my problem with the following solution. 
I installed Boot repair and repaired my file system. I have LVM(logical volume mangement) and i couldnt run fsck. you can follow how to install it from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
 or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

after that, boot-repair should open automatically

1. click the "**advanced options**" to expand
2. in the "**Main options**" tab, check "**Reinstall GRUB**" and "**Repair file systems**" Repairing file systems is the most important part as the kernel panics happen because of some file system error.
3. int the "**Grub options**" tab, check "**Purge GRUB before reinstalling it**"
4. and of course you must have internet connection as you will be installing new files.
   and finally click **Apply**.

Answer (score 1):

You had this problem because your kernel is not signed and your system is in safe boot.  Even if you disable safeboot, you may get an error like `Kernel not syncing : -Vfs`

1. In the GRUB bootloader, choose advanced options and then select and older kernel version to boot into your system.
2. Open up the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Then check your available kernel using the command, `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`
4. Update to the latest kernel or get the latest kernel with the commands:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get upgrade linux-image-generic
   ```

   `sudo apt-get upgrade linux-image-generic` is optional

Now the new kernels will be downloaded.

Then reboot the system.  The new kernel will be assigned as the main kernel instead of the previous unsigned one!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2c for those encountering this problem when running virtual machines. I was seeing the same message when trying to use VM migrated from VirtualBox to VMWare ESXi. None of the solutions above have worked to resolve the issue, the only option that resolved the issue was to manually convert the disk image into VMWare format:

```
 /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager -r ubuntu-disk1.vmdk -t 4 ../ubuntu-disk.vmdk
```

The important part being the -t 4, which creates ESXi-ready disk image. I've used VMWare Fusion as an example but any distribution of the vmware-vdiskmanager can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone.
The same problem was occurring for me on all the 4 available kernels on my laptop.
I have tried various methods like fsck, nomodeset,selinux=0. Nothing was working.

I fixed the error with a live ubuntu usb. 
Booted from live usb  and run these commands

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mv /mnt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /mnt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-copy
sudo mkdir /mnt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /mnt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then umount /dev/sda1  and reboot (remove the usb).
It worked for me.

Comment: [deeper debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/init.html), adjust your version!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue in my removable USB stick which was made bootable using ventoy.
Was fixed when "boot from grub2" was selected instead of "boot in normal mode".
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the memory RAM.
i remove a memory RAM 2 Gb.
In this case i had 2 memory ram than 2Gb only remove 1 memory and it working