# Kernel panic after Ubuntu update.

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)

I updated Ubuntu and when I rebooted, it won't boot. I get a black screen with the error `Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init`

I use `Ubuntu 12.04`, my linux-image is `3.2.0-33-generic-pae`,recovery mode goes into the same error (`Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init`) and Ubuntu upgraded my previous linux versions as well and they all go into that same error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may load Ubuntu by selecting previous version and than selecting the corresponding kernel in that option. The problem generally arises when you have 64-bit kernel and updating causes a generic-pae 32-bit kernel to apear along with the previous one. Thus causing the problem.

Once you are able to boot, you may remove the generic-pae kernel by the following steps:

1. `sudo update-grub`. It will show you grub.cfg file and you can see the two kernels present.
2. `sudo rm /boot/*generic-pae`
3. `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe reinstalling OS is the best (no time consuming) choice on this type of messages.
There is another similar problem: [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init) fixed with reinstall OS.

Comment: Before I reinstall the OS, how can I backup my Ubuntu data so it won't get lost?