# Did a re-install after installing windows and now I am getting a kernel panic

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, kernel, windows-8

My windows was showing problems so I restored it to the factory version.

Once I did that my Laptop would directly boot to Windows. So I thought it must have formatted the Ubuntu partition as well. So I went ahead and reinstalled 13.04 via a Live CD.It was successful. Post this re-install I cannot boot into Ubuntu anymore as there is a **kernel Panic: not syncing attempted to kill init**

I dont know how to correct this problem. Please help

P.s. - I am  novice user and I have just started using ubuntu ( well almost )

> Edit: Ijust did a memory test as well, and it said "Pass complete no errors."

Comment: Please read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and see if they help you.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/92946/169736

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Danatela, Braiam, I just did a clean install. earlier I had re-installed. this time I re-installed while erasing the previous installation.
This helped me solve my problem although my data is now lost. But atleast I do have the system up again.

Thanks,

P.S.- Also Braiam I dont really see any solution in the link that you have attached.