# Ubuntu failing to boot past GRUB - "Kernel panic"

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, kernel, virtualbox

So I've been working today on developing a LFS system, I'm developing the system using a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu.

I got to [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/glibc.html) page, and after running the `make install` command for Glibc the virtualbox was slow, and some basic commands like cp where acting weird (it was saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)") so I decided to restart the VB.

After selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu, I was presented by this awesome(not) error dump:

[image]

Can you guys tell me what this means, and maybe how to fix my VM?

**EDIT 1:**

It also throws the same error when attempting to boot into recovery mode.

I did accidentally run a chmod command on the wrong partition, but I don't think it would cause this. (I accidentally changed the LFS host system's "/var/log/btmp" file to 660 from whatever it was before)

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the kernel log from `/var/log/kern.log` http://pastebin.com/TusqDGrP

**EDIT 3:**

This is similar to [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init) except that I'm not getting an error as far as I can see

Comment: It's probably better to use **eglibc** on 14.04, or upgrade the distribution to >= 15.04 for support of **glibc**.

Comment: @Takkat I'm just following what the book says to use, or do you mean on the LFS host?

Answer (score 0):

I decided instead of waiting to get help, I would just format and reinstall the boot partition with my Ubuntu ISO.

Is anyone knows what happened there though, I would be interested to know.