# end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

This is my first time trying to do something like this so please excuse my incompetence. I've been trying to run Linux on a virtual machine.

When I created the new VM I chose the Ubuntu 32 bit version of Linux and then I chose all the default selections from there.

As for the start-up disk I chose the ISO that I downloaded from [here](http://download.cnet.com/Ubuntu-32-bit/3000-18513_4-170729.html) and I get this:

[image]

This being my first time doing this I do not understand the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: u need to enable vt-x in bios.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)