# Ubuntu 18.04 install failure from USB stick

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb

My problem might be a combination of two problems:

1. After an installation of python3-dev package on my Ubuntu 16.04 I was asked to reboot. Reboot was not successfull even in a recovery mode. Following error appeared:

   ```
   Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
   ```

   You can follow this link for basically the same problem (non of the solutions worked for me): [Attempted to kill init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init).
2. Finally I decided to install a newer Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04). I created bootable USB using Rufus 3.1 and successfully booted USB. I accessed welcoming menu with options and selected Install Ubuntu.
   I received the same Kernel panic error. With the same USB I can install Ubuntu on another computer without problems. If that helps, PC is bootable in Windows 7. I tried to search in BIOS but found nothing suspicious.

Anybody any idea how to fix this please???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  The first thing I'd try is a `fsck` (`xfs_check` or a file system check as appropriate for your file system) from your 'live' install-media. If any errors, or issues are found, I"d then try rebooting your [existing] Ubuntu system.

Comment: Did you got this error during installation or after installation?

Comment: guiverc: I am trying to use fsck from live usb but somehow I cannot open terminal
abu_bua: neither... I get this error after I select Install Ubuntu from the menu

Comment: guiverc: selection of any option - even Try without installation gives the same Kernel error