# Attempted to kill init! Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, virtualbox

version: 14.04

windows: win10

I forced VirtualBox off this morning, it keeps showing this image:
[image: virtualbox]

Then, I tried repairing and reinstalling Ubuntu.
Now, I can't boot up it as that "Attempted to kill init!" occurred repeatedly, no matter which way to reboot.

[image: error message]

[image: reboot_1]

[image: reboot_2]

What can I do for saving files and my previous environment?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init

Comment: I don't think I'm in the same situation with this one. I read and tried, still don't work

Comment: Can you run the `recovery mode` from within grub? You may need to reinstall the kernel.