# End kernel panic - error while trying to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, crash

So, while trying to boot Ubuntu (or any Linux), I get this error message.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytqG7.jpg

"end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000009"

I've used Ubuntu before and no such error has happened while trying to boot it.

I'm currently using Windows 7 on this machine, and every time I try to boot up any version of Linux, I get the error message above. I can't even get into the Live Media to try it out, it crashes as soon as it starts booting up.

Comment: The first screenfull is the more important image to get.

Comment: status please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **http://www.memtest.org** or **https://www.memtest86.com/** (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I try booting the memtest, it still shows up the same error.

Comment: @Spr1nt Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, download memtest and run it from there. If you can't boot to the Live media, you must have a hardware problem. Is this a desktop or laptop? Do you know how much memory you have, and in what configuration? Report back.

Comment: I cant boot to Ubuntu Live, it's a desktop, it's using 2 sticks of DDR2 memory (Both 2GB).

Comment: @Spr1nt  Power down the machine. Unplug from AC. Hold down the power button for 10 seconds. Carefully remove one of the two sticks of RAM, noting which slot it was in. If it doesn't boot, put that stick back in, and remove the other stick, also noting which slot it was in. Once it boots, run memtest on the remaining stick.