# End kernel panic -not syncing : Attempted to kill init! Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel, init

I want to restart my computer. It is dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. When I am on Ubuntu I want to restart my computer and it shows this picture what should I do? I can't type anything.

[image: error picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot boot because: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling your Ubuntu, using a Live CD / USB to fix your boot files. More info is on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init?rq=1)